# Do I need to keep the plugin tag in the config.xml in cordova?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

In cordova 9 the plugins' info was shifted from `config.xml` to the `package.json`, and since then every time I add a plugin it will not be added at `config.xml`.

May I fully erase the `plugin` tags in `config.xml`, since they are not even updated? Or do I need them for any sort of backward compatibility?

```xml
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1"/>
```

Comment: You can remove the `<plugin>` tags from `config.xml` so long as they have been migrated to `package.json`.

Comment: @DaveAlden please reply accordingly in an independent answer, such that I can set it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `<plugin>` tags from `config.xml` so long as they have been migrated to `package.json` (their package versions should be in `devDependencies` and any plugin variables in `cordova.plugins`) since recent versions of the [Cordova CLI](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli) uses `package.json` as the source of plugin info.

Comment: But how do you define platform specific plugins now in `package.json` ?